# MVC - Authentication Bypass using HTTP verb Tampering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have built a web application using MVC3 and got an AppScan result from ITSec department. I have been told to implement below recommendation.

Configure your application to allow only required HTTP methods.

In ASP.NET Authorization: use `<deny verbs="*" users="*" />` after allowing a white list of required verbs.

Here my question is, how to identify required HTTP methods for my application. 
How to categorize White list and black list of HTTP verbs. What are the methods should be in White list.

I could see below list of methods from Web.

- HEAD •   GET •   POST •  PUT •   DELETE •    TRACE • OPTIONS •   CONNECT

Comment: GET and POST should be in White list. These two are basic methods.

Comment: You can read each method definitions here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html, then decide which ones should put in whitelist (GET & POST are must be whitelisted).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Is there any possibility to identify what are all the 
 HTTP verbs already used in my application using developer tools or any other shortcut.

Comment: @Ask_SO I think you can utilize `System.Net.Http.HttpMethod` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod(v=vs.118).aspx) but I'm not sure if you can get used verbs in all requests with that (consider to see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70561/how-to-identify-the-http-methods-supported-by-a-web-server).

Comment: hi @Ask_SO I am also getting same error in IBM app scan and my application is in MVC 5, do you got the solution for the same?